# li tag with condition creating empty spaces when condition is not satisfied

Tags: html, angular, html-lists, angular-ng-if

I am working on an angular application. I am trying to create a list and have a check condition in my `<li>` tag. When the condition is not met, I do not want to create an item. My code

```
<ul>
    <li [style.visibility]="data.First == 'Y' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <span>
            First Item
        </span>
    </li>
    <li  [style.visibility]="data.Second == 'Y' ? 'visible' : 'hidden'">
        <span>
            Second Item
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

When the conditions are not met item is not added in list but empty space is created for that row. How do I avoid creating an empty row? I have also tried with *ngIf but that is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That how [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/visibility) works to avoid empty row try

```
<li  [style.display]="data.Second == 'Y' ? 'block' : 'none'">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using `*ngIf`. Check below code.
if your condition result is true angular create or add an item(`<li>` element) otherwise skipped that element.

```
<ul>
    <li *ngIf="data.First == 'Y'">
        <span>
            First Item
        </span>
    </li>
    <li  *ngIf="data.Second == 'Y'">
        <span>
            Second Item
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output a list of length n, I would recommend something like this:

```
<ul>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let entry of data; let index = index">
        <li *ngIf="entry.myParameter == 'Y'">
            <span>{{ index }} item</span>
        </li>
    </ng-container>
</ul>
```